# Updating label text in PyQT after drag & drop event

Tags: python, pyqt, drag-and-drop, pyqt5, label

I'm just crash coursing UI in Python but it seems I've hit this interesting wall and I'd appreciate some help.

My code is:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication
import sys
from subprocess import check_output
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import * 
from PyQt5.QtGui import * 
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui 
from PyQt5.QtCore import * 
import json
import time


class MainWidget(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("GAINWARD EDGE Antivirus")
        self.resize(504, 590)
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 520, 141, 21))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.LFileName = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.LFileName.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(210, 50, 91, 21))
        self.LFileName.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.LFileName.setLineWidth(19)
        self.LFileName.setObjectName("LFileName")
        self.LCrowdStrike = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.LCrowdStrike.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 190, 131, 16))
        self.LCrowdStrike.setObjectName("LCrowdStrike")
        self.LHash = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.LHash.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(210, 90, 91, 21))
        self.LHash.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.LHash.setLineWidth(19)
        self.LHash.setObjectName("LHash")
        self.LMetaDefender = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.LMetaDefender.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 240, 131, 16))
        self.LMetaDefender.setObjectName("LMetaDefender")
        self.LVirusTotal = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.LVirusTotal.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 290, 131, 16))
        self.LVirusTotal.setObjectName("LVirusTotal")
        self.StatCrowd = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.StatCrowd.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 180, 111, 41))
        self.StatCrowd.setObjectName("StatCrowd")
        self.StatMeta = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.StatMeta.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 230, 111, 41))
        self.StatMeta.setObjectName("StatMeta")
        self.StatVirus = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.StatVirus.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 280, 111, 41))
        self.StatVirus.setObjectName("StatVirus")


        self.retranslateUi(self)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(self)


    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Exit"))
        self.LFileName.setText(_translate("Dialog", "FileName"))
        self.LCrowdStrike.setText(_translate("Dialog", "CrowdStrike Falcon:"))
        self.LHash.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Hash"))
        self.LMetaDefender.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Metadefender:"))
        self.LVirusTotal.setText(_translate("Dialog", "VirusTotal:"))
        self.StatCrowd.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Status1"))
        self.StatMeta.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Status2"))
        self.StatVirus.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Status3"))

    def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasUrls():
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()

    def foobar():
        ui.LFileName.setText(f)
        ui.LHash.setText("???")
        ui.StatCrowd.setText(crowdStrikeStatus)
        ui.StatMeta.setText(metaDefenderStatus)
        ui.StatVirus.setText(virusTotalStatus)

    def dropEvent(self, event):
        files = [u.toLocalFile() for u in event.mimeData().urls()]
        for f in files:

            out = check_output(["C:\\Users\\lilra\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\python.exe", "C:\\Users\\lilra\\Desktop\\dev\\pyqt\\VxAPI\\vxapi.py", "scan_file", f"{f}", "all"])

            crowdStrikeName = json.loads(out)['scanners'][0]['name']
            crowdStrikeStatus = json.loads(out)['scanners'][0]['status']

            if "no-result" in crowdStrikeStatus:
                crowdStrikeStatus = "No detection [OK]"

            print(f"{crowdStrikeName}: {crowdStrikeStatus}")

            metaDefenderName = json.loads(out)['scanners'][1]['name']
            metaDefenderStatus = json.loads(out)['scanners'][1]['status']

            if "clean" in metaDefenderStatus:
                metaDefenderStatus = "No detection [OK]"

            print(f"{metaDefenderName}: {metaDefenderStatus}")

            virusTotalName = json.loads(out)['scanners'][2]['name']
            virusTotalStatus = json.loads(out)['scanners'][2]['status']

            if "no-result" in virusTotalStatus:
                virusTotalStatus = "No detection [OK]"

            print(f"{virusTotalName}: {virusTotalStatus}")


            VirusTotal.setText('Hello, world!')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ui = MainWidget()
    ui.show()
    splash = QSplashScreen()
    splash.setPixmap(QPixmap('obbac2wjcpvenbtcg8zi.png').scaled(770, 830))
    splash.show()
    splash.showMessage('<h1 style="color:white;">Gainward EDGE Antivirus Initializing...</h1>', 
                       Qt.AlignTop | Qt.AlignHCenter, Qt.white)    
    time.sleep(1)

    splash.hide()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

So after the drop event, it should maybe do something like this:

```
    def foobar():
        ui.LFileName.setText(f)
        ui.LHash.setText("sample API response text")
        ui.StatCrowd.setText(crowdStrikeStatus)
        ui.StatMeta.setText(metaDefenderStatus)
        ui.StatVirus.setText(virusTotalStatus)
```

but I'm having difficulty acheiving this.

To recap I'm making an API call after a drop event of a file, then trying to update the text labels with the parsed results of the API response.

Comment: Please provide a minium example about the specific problem do you have. Also you can have more information adding some prints to see if the drag and drop events are really triggered. Itś possible that you need to setAcceptDrops at the widget level

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**this will works:**

```
class MainWidget(QMainWindow):
    ...

    def dragLeaveEvent(self, event):
        self.foobar(file_info=('-', '-'))

    def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasUrls():
            event.accept()
            file = event.mimeData().urls()[0]
            file_info = self.get_file_info(file=file)
            self.foobar(file_info=file_info)
        else:
            event.ignore()

    @staticmethod
    def get_file_info(file):
        hasher = hashlib.md5()

        with open(file.toLocalFile(), 'rb') as f:
            hasher.update(f.read())

        filename = file.fileName()
        _hash = hasher.hexdigest()
        return filename, _hash
    
    # UPDATE UI
    def foobar(self, file_info):
        self.LFileName.setText(file_info[0])
        self.LHash.setText(file_info[1])
```